# Is there a type definition for Typescript to allow anything BUT `any`?

Tags: typescript, generics, any

In our open source library [@thisisagile/easy](https://github.com/thisisagile/easy). We have defined a type `Get<T = unknown, Args = unknown> = T | Func<T, Args>` (see [`Get`](https://github.com/thisisagile/easy/blob/main/packages/easy/src/types/Get.ts)), which is either a function or an object, and a function `ofGet<T>()` that evaluates it.

In some edge cases, however, when we define a get from a function that returns an `any`, the behavior is different than what you would expect. I imagine this has to do with that the compiler can't see the difference and chooses the evaluate the use of the type as `any` instead of `() => any`.

So, I'm wondering if we could define a conditional type where we could exclude `any`, e.g. `Get<T, Args> = IsAnAny<T> ? Func<T, Args> : (Func<T, Args> | T)`. Any ideas?